# 3 thread running at high frequency uses the same variables

Tags: android, concurrency, android-handler, java-threads, android-ble

I'm developing an android application that at high frequency receives data from ble notify, print data on the screen and send data to other peripherall.

This is my situation :

1. onCharacteristicChanged callback  receives a byte array called
   "**value**" at 10hz and unpacks data in some float and int variables
2. an Handler associated with an handlerThread starts a Runnable
       every 30hz. This runnable use the variables unpacked from **value**,
       saves the new data in some variables and sendbroadcastmessage to the
       UX
3. another thread every 10hz use the data saved in
           step 1 and 2 does some math operation on this variables and write
           data on the characteristic.

In the step above I save and use float, double and int variables.

I'm afraid to handles the concurrency and I'm thinking to resolve the concurrency problems using the same handlerthread in the step 2 and 3. But when the other notify arrives I think that there is a race condiction problem :/

**other question :** oncharacteristicchanged in what thread is executed ?

**more information of my problem :**
in oncharacteristicchanged arrives new byte array (at 10hz frequency), I unpack data in variables , in other thread B (at 30hz) use this data do some calculation: sendbroadcast to the ux and save the result in some other variables; the thread C use the result of the thread B, it does some other calculation and write on characteristic at 10hz.

oncharacteristicchanged -> Thread B -> Thread C

But I can't stop oncharacteristicchanged because I don't know in what thread it is executed..

Do you

Comment: You may want to start with _Java Concurrency in Practice_ (http://jcip.net/).

Comment: Yes I have to buy that book , but before  i have to resolve problem above :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand Android, but I do Java. I'll try to help you even not knowing Android, so let's go!

*"In the step above I save and use float, double and int variables."*

First of all, I'd start using thread safe variables, such as: AtomicInteger or declare them as volatile.

For all your methods that will be accessed by multi-threading, I'd say to make them thread safe. I don't know if in Android there is the class Lock or the keyword synchronized, but I'd start from there.

Example:

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
try  {
    lock.lock();
    doYourWork();
} finally{
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Thats the way to start... Hope I helped you a little bit even not knowing Android and sorry if I said anything wrong.

Comment: Thanks to the answer. Initially i have thought to use lock object, but what happen if the new data arrives in the oncharacteristicchanged and in the meanwhile the other thread is holding the lock ?

Comment: Then the Thread acessing oncharacteristicchanged  should wait until Thread holding the lock, unlock the object. 

Example:

`MyClass mc = new MyClass();`
`mc.wait(); //hold the lock of the object`
`doStuff();`
`mc.notify(); //release the lock to anyother thread take it!`

Also, use it inside a thread safe method and make sure to always unlock your objetcs to avoid threading stuck and be careful with deadlock (I suggest you to read about it)!

Comment: Thanks. But I think that the oncharacteristicchanged runs in the U thread, therefor I shouldn't stop it .. however I wonder if the oncharacteristicchanged really runs in ui thread or not .. mmm ..

Comment: Ps: when you use the method wait(), make sure it's inside a synchronized block, or otherlese it will throw java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException. Also, I suggest to set a time to wait for the object lock using the wait(int), so you can avoid the Threading stuck.

Comment: Of course you can stop it. Calling the join() method on the Thread class make all the other thread wait for the one calling join().

Example:

`Thread t1 = new Thread(your runnable here);`
`t1.join(); // Hey other threads, wait for me to end my job, then you can` `continue from here. `

Comment: Sorry i did an error in the msg above. I would to say that I don't know if oncharacteristicchanged runs in the UI thread (Thread in android that handles the graphics) I shouldn't stop that thread. If I can't stop oncharacteristicchanged in what way can I do ?